# AJAX POST data does not show up in Python

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, flask

I make this `HTTP POST` Request using `jQuery`.

```
function getData() {

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "test_id": "1"
    });

    jQuery.post('/getData', data, function (response) {
        alert("success");
        console.log(response)

    }, "json");
}
```

When I receive the request in Python, when I try to print `request.data`, the string is empty.

When I attach the debugger, I see that data are under `form` (`request.form`).

How can I make them accessible from `request.data` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to set content type header if you send json. Default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To send form encoded don't use JSON.stringify

Comment: what do you use in Python - Flask, Django, other ? Maybe check `request.json`

Comment: you are sending to python POST request with `test_id=1` but trying to check variable `data`

Comment: @diavolic, yes, when i Send the same request from postman, the test_id is in `request.data`

Comment: @furas, I use Flask

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could see what you have in `Flask` and we could simply copy it and test ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send parameters as `{}` so you could use `contentType`.

Doc: [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```js
    jQuery.post({
        url: "/getData",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
            console.log(response);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
```

Using `contentType: 'application/json'` you should get it as `request.data` but also as `request.json` which can be more useful.

---

Minimal working code

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
function getData() {

    const data = JSON.stringify({"test_id": "1"});

    jQuery.post({
        url: "/getData",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
            console.log(response);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
getData();
</script>
</head>
</html>
''')

@app.route('/getData', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    print('args :', request.args)
    print('form :', request.form)
    print('data :', request.data)
    print('json :', request.json)
    print('files:', request.files)
    return jsonify(["Hello World"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Result:

```
args : ImmutableMultiDict([])
form : ImmutableMultiDict([])
data : b'{"test_id":"1"}'
json : {'test_id': '1'}
files: ImmutableMultiDict([])
```